# Drawing splines using openGL

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, curve, spline

I try to draw a spline using openGL and Java.

What I have now is just a set of points. What I want is a spline, which goes through each of these points.

Is there a special function in openGL for accomplish it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a special function in openGL for accomplish it?

No. And later versions of OpenGL (v3 and later) did focus on deprecating and removing anything specialized. You can write a combination of tesselation, geometry and vertex shaders that generate a tesselated bezier spline from a set of input points. But you'll have to write those shaders yourself.